# How Do I Link An Object File Into a UEFI DXE/EFI Driver?

Tags: linker, .obj, uefi, object-files, edk2

I am building a UEFI DXE/EFI (UDK2018) driver (on Windows, using VS2017) into which I need to link an existing object (`.obj`) file. I'm fairly certain this should be done from inside the **INF** file, but I don't see anything specific about object file inclusion in the EDK2 documentation. I did find these two examples for reference:

https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/UDK2018/StdLib/LibC/LibC.inf#L96

```
[Binaries.X64]
LIB|Twofish_x64.obj|*
LIB|Camellia_aesni_x64.obj|*
LIB|Camellia_x64.obj|*
```

https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt-DCS/blob/master/Library/VeraCryptLib/VeraCryptLib.inf#L79

```
[Binaries.IA32]
  LIB|Main/Ia32/ftol2.obj|*|MSFT
```

However, even with these as reference (which I assume work), I am unable to figure out the right way to configure the **INF** file to get the **`object_files.lst`** to include the `.obj`. (The actual error is, of course, an unresolved external. -- I have verified that if I manually add the `.obj` file to the **`object_files.lst`**, the link of the `.efi` driver succeeds.)

Without the `.obj`, my **INF** looks like this:

```
[Defines]
  INF_VERSION                    = 0x00010005
  BASE_NAME                      = SampleDxe
  FILE_GUID                      = XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
  MODULE_TYPE                    = DXE_DRIVER
  VERSION_STRING                 = 1.0
  ENTRY_POINT                    = SampleDxe_Main

[Sources]
  SampleDXE.c
  SampleDXE.h
  SampleProtocol.h

[Packages]
  MdePkg/MdePkg.dec
  MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dec

[LibraryClasses]
  UefiBootServicesTableLib
  MemoryAllocationLib
  UefiDriverEntryPoint
  BaseMemoryLib
  UefiLib
  DebugLib
  BaseLib
  PcdLib
  DevicePathLib

[Depex]
  TRUE
```

I have tried inserting the following sections between the `[Sources]` and `[Packages]` sections, without any success:

```
[Binaries]
  LIB|path/to/my/file.obj|*|MSFT
```

```
[Binaries.X64]
  LIB|path/to/my/file.obj|*|MSFT
```

```
[Binaries]
  LIB|path/to/my/file.obj|*
```

```
[Binaries.X64]
  LIB|path/to/my/file.obj|*
```

```
[Binaries]
  LIB|path/to/my/file.obj
```

```
[Binaries.X64]
  LIB|path/to/my/file.obj
```

(`.obj` placed with source files)

```
[Binaries]
  LIB|file.obj|*|MSFT
```

```
[Binaries.X64]
  LIB|file.obj|*|MSFT
```

```
[Binaries]
  LIB|file.obj|*
```

```
[Binaries.X64]
  LIB|file.obj|*
```

```
[Binaries]
  LIB|file.obj
```

```
[Binaries.X64]
  LIB|file.obj
```

I have also modified the INF_VERSION to later versions (0x0001001A, 1.25, etc.), although not with every combination of the sections above.

I also believe I could create an intermediate `.lib` file, but if I'm going to do that, there are other, more direct options that make sense in my case. The use of the stand-alone object file would be preferable, simpler, and more cooperative with other pieces of the larger project, and the examples above sure seem to indicate this should be possible.

Can anyone tell me how I can get a pre-existing object file to link into the DXE/EFI (presumably by getting it added to the **`object_files.lst`**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I should have figured that after several days of trying, the answer would appear just after I posted this question...and it did.

I was first directed to the default **`EDK\Conf\build_rule.txt`** file, and looking through there, I found a build rule for `.obj` files (as well as `.o` files)! This looked a lot like a plain copy (well, actually adding it to the same list as the output of `.c`/`.cpp`/`.asm`/etc. files), so the idea was suggested to try placing the `.obj` file into the `[Sources]` section. I had not seen that anywhere else, so I tried, and sure enough, it worked:

```
[Sources]
  SampleDXE.c
  SampleDXE.h
  SampleProtocol.h
  path/to/my/file.obj
```

Comment: Were you able to use some sort of macro definition to point the obj file relative to the output dir, build target and supported architecture?

Comment: My apologies. This was several years ago at a previous employer, so I don't have access to the code & don't recall all the details. Plus, I'm not currently working on UEFI.

I do know that this product was for a specific architecture, so we did not need to worry about those variations. However, there are pre-defined constants for the architecture details. If there are not relative (or absolute) paths, at the very least, the path could be built up from the directory names.